# Define spark context in jupyter-kernel-gateway

Tags: ipython, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have spark and jupyter running and in a notebook when I run `sc` I get `<pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x7f8b8c173d50>` which is great. Now I am trying to run each cell in this notebook as an endpoint using https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http-mode.html. I start up jupyter kernel gateway from the command line as `jupyter kernelgateway --KernelGatewayApp.api=kernel_gateway.notebook_http --KernelGatewayApp.seed_uri=notebooks/Spark_Test.ipynb` and that works fine. It's only when I try to run the cell that gets the spark context where I get a 500 and it says `Error NameError: name 'sc' is not defined`. Is there a way to get the spark context when starting up the kernel gateway? I have searched all over and am pretty lost on how to do this.

If it's relevant, I start spark and jupyter by running `<path to spark home>/bin/pyspark`. The kergnel-gateway and spark/jupyter are both also running in different shells.